# MongoDB Insert Polyline and query nearby

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial, mongodb-java

I'm having a series of points which forms a poly-line (path). I need to store it in the mongodb and query it nearby point.

How to store a poly-line in the mongodb?

Can i query it with a $near?

After saving the poly-line to mongodb, i will have a point and distance from the point and need to query the db.

**EDIT :**

i'm gone track the user's location using the GPS and i need to save the path in mongodb, how to do this?

Then the user can able to search path nearby his place with certain distance so i need to search the mongodb with the $near function.

Comment: The available types are listed in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/#geojson-objects). Outside of that you are usually better off asking questions by explaining your use case and the results you want to achieve. Clear explanations like that allow others to think "outside the box" that you might be currently thinking in.

Comment: So you mean a [LineString](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#linestring), right? A list of co-ordinates mapping a path taken. That is supported.

Comment: ya correct
can i know how to do it.?

Comment: can you tell me that how to insert line string into mongodb using java?

Comment: If you are referring to the supplied answer not being in Java driver syntax then I will say 1. Translation is not hard, 2. There are built in operations in the driver that convert JSON to BSON objects as expected by the driver, 3. The answer gave you insight you did not posses before and is useful, 4.  If you have clarifications pertaining to the answer then respond on the answer and not your question.

Answer (score 2):

So what you want is actually a [LineString](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#linestring) GeoJSON type, which is supported by MongoDB:

```js
{ 
    "loc": { 
        "type": "LineString", 
        "coordinates": [ [ 40, 5 ], [ 41, 6 ] ] 
     }
}
```

This allows you record a set of "coordinates" along a "path" that you wish to contain as a singular object in your data store. The main beauty of this is that you can do geospatial queries against such an object ( rather than a distinct "Point" and retrieve the whole "set" of connecting "Points" in a single document as "nearest". Better yet "multiple shapes" like this can be matched with ease.

So then you can just query with [**`$near`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) or other operators as appropriate:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "loc": {
        "$near": {
            "$geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ 41,5 ]
            },
            "$maxDistance": 10000
        }
     }
})
```

A [**`$near`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) operator in a query will return the results ordered by the "nearest" to the queried GeoJSON object or legacy coordinate point provided to the query.

That should basically work for you.

Comment: i can able to insert linestring like this in mongo shell using java driver, But when i try to insert it in mongo server it throws error as   "location object expected, location array not in correct format"

Comment: @Achuthan The general idea is to try "prototyping ideas" using the mongo shell and on a local instance where you can "play". Aside from my general 80%/20% rule that programming is mostly about problem solving ability, the next context is "test", "test", and "test" again. I gave you a small sample that reproduces everywhere, so just do that first and then work out the rest of your problems.

Comment: i just want to know whats the error message is, 
ok its not a problem i'll find the solution. 

THANKS for your help

Comment: @Achuthan What error message? And in what context? Just input the above into the shell and "learn". It works for the rest of the world, and you need to understand that.